# anchor tag in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, anchor

**Found it difficult to frame the question, here's my problem.**

*alert.html*

```
<div class="alert_text">
 <%= link_to "Comment", :action=>:show, :id=>lp.id %>
</div>
```

when I click on the link it takes me to show page

*show.html*

table is displayed at beginning of the page after that, below part of code.

```
 <div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial=>'comments' %>
 </div>
```

what I need is, when I click on **link Comment** it must load show page as normal but should direct to **comments part of page**.

**Edit**: Just like as it happens in this **stackoverflow.com**, on top left **StackExchange** when you click on *inbox* message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the `anchor` option with a path helper. Assuming you're using RESTful routing, you should be able to do something like:

```
<%= link_to "Comments", my_model_path(lp, anchor: 'comments') %>
```

You would need to change `my_model` to the whatever your resource is called. So if you have `resources :articles` in routes.rb, it would be `article_path(lp, anchor: 'comments')`

Comment: I used it this way and got it right                               <%= link_to "Comment", :action=>:show, :id=>lp.id, :anchor=> 'lessonplan_comments' %>

Answer (score 0):

Give your comment div an ID and use it link this:

```
<%= link_to "Comment##{lp.id}", :action=>:show %>
```

If the div comment has your ID, it will straight go to that spot.